# How to cast java Object to generic collection safely?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, casting, classcastexception

I can cast simple java objects safely by doing something like:

```
Object str = "test";
Optional.of(str)
      .filter(value -> value instanceof String)
      .map(String.class::cast)
      .ifPresent(value -> System.out.println("Here is the value: " + value));
```

But how can I do the same stuff casting object to a generic collection?

For example:

```
Object entries = /**/;
// this is unsafe
List<Entry<String, String>> subscriptions = (List<Entry<String, String>>) entries;
```

How should I handle situation like this and is there any library (something like ClassCastUtils) to help with such convertion?

Comment: You can't. Fancy lambdas won't make erasure go away.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica how should I handle this situation then?

Comment: @TyulpanTyulpan why are you in that situation? Why do you have an `Object`?

Comment: You should explain `X`, you have currently asked about `Y` in your XY problem.

Comment: Please not only post a snippet of code but rather a running minimal example so we don't run into XY-Problems speculating about your use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really a good way to do it. The naive approach would be to

1. Check it's a list/set/collection
2. Check all the items are `Entry`s
3. Check all the keys and values of each `Entry` are `String`s

For example

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "b");
Object entries = map.entrySet();

boolean safe = Optional.of(entries)
    .filter(Set.class::isInstance)
    .map(e -> (Set<?>) e)
    .filter(set -> set.stream().allMatch(Map.Entry.class::isInstance))
    .map(e -> (Set<Map.Entry<?, ?>>) e)
    .filter(set -> set.stream().allMatch(e -> e.getKey() instanceof String && e.getValue() instanceof String))
    .isPresent();
```

However, even this doesn't give enough assurance. Suppose the map was declared as:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "b");
```

At the time of our check, this would be seen as safe. It's a set and all the entries are currently strings. However, if some other code were to later mutate the map, for example

```
map.add("b", 123);
```

Then you will realise that this cast is still unsafe. You can only work with the current state, so you can't make any guarantees about future state.

You may be able to get around this in a couple of ways:

1. Deep copy the entire collection after checking. But what about the race condition after having checked before before having copied? You would have to use a lock.
2. Make the map immutable

How about if it is a collection but it's currently empty? In that case, you can't make any checks against the items.

As you can see, working with such a cast is very hard work and has many places where you could potentially go wrong. Your best bet is to avoid having to make such a cast in the first place.

Comment: You don't need a lock, if you combine the check with the cast, i.e. read a reference into a local variable, check it, cast it, pass it to the constructor/factory of the new immutable object. But this gets even more complicated than the chain you've posted. So it might be simpler to optimistically cast  while creating the deep copy and catch the exception.